# How do I swap text in regex and convert month to number equivalent?

Tags: notepad++, regex

I'm struggling to solve this problem in Notepad++. I'd really appreciate a good answer.

Let's say I have this line:

`INSERT INTO example VALUES ('P1', 'V1', '27-Apr-2004', 20.00, '123', '1234');`

And I want to get this:

`INSERT INTO example VALUES ('P1', 'V1', '2004-04-27', 20.00, '123', '1234');`

How can I do this for all lines in Notepad++? I've tried different kind of things but I couldn't get this result.

Comment: I would use one regex to change the order of day, month and year, e.g. `27-Apr-2004` would become `2004-Apr-27`, then use 12 separate replacements for the month names, i.e. replace `-Apr-` with `-04-` etc. If a leading 0 is necessary for the day, you might need another regex replacement. The whole taskmight be easier to solve with a script (awk, perl, python, ...).

Comment: If the type of the field is date or datetime, it might be easier to insert some kind of database specific conversion function into your SQL. For instance, for SQL Server that could look like `cast('27-Apr-2004' as date)`. Find what would then be `('\d{1,2}-\l{3}-\d{4}')`, and Replace with: `cast\(\1 as date\)`